# ffmpeg stereo to mono conversion produces different result when piping the output vs writing to a file

Tags: command-line, audio, ffmpeg

I've utilised ffmpeg to read a stereo audio file and convert it to mono outputting the audio data in format `f32le` onto `stdout`. Eg:

```
ffmpeg -i ff-16b-2c-44100hz.flac -ac 1 -ar 44100 -f f32le "pipe:1" > out.bin
```

It uses `-ac 1` to reduce the output to mono, sets the format `-f f32le` and pipes it to stdout `pipe:1` which is written into `out.bin`

Loading `out.bin` in Audacity (File > Import > Raw Data) shows values going above 1.0 and below -1.0. It appears that converting the audio to mono increases its gain.

Doing the same stereo to mono conversion but writing it to a file directly with ffmpeg, produces a better result where it doesn't increase the gain of the audio.

```
ffmpeg -i ff-16b-2c-44100hz.flac -ac 1 -ar 44100 out.flac
```

Here is a comparison of the results loaded inside Audacity:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBA6O.png

Any idea on why this happens and if there are configuration options I'm missing for the piped version to not increase the gain?

Comment: Check if `-f s32le` works as expected.

Comment: `-f s32le` works when piping it to stdout. Any idea if the behaviour for `-f f32le` should be considered a bug in ffmpeg or is it expected behaviour and I'm missing the right configuration option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The audio resampler is applying different matrix coefficients (visible with `-loglevel debug`). f32le is on top, s32le/s16le on bottom:

```
[auto_resampler_0 @ 0x55de59fe8bc0] [SWR @ 0x55de59fe8fc0] FC: FL:0.707107 FR:0.707107
[auto_resampler_0 @ 0x56515b7fdbc0] [SWR @ 0x56515b7fdfc0] FC: FL:0.500000 FR:0.500000
```

So the downmixed f32le output results in higher gain. I don't know why it is doing that. Maybe I can look into it later.

One workaround is to manually apply the desired mix by using the [pan filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pan):

```
ffmpeg -i ff-16b-2c-44100hz.flac -af "pan=mono|c0=0.5*FL+0.5*FR" -ar 44100 -f f32le "pipe:1" > out.bin
```

In this case it should be the same as using the pan gain re-normalization:

```
ffmpeg -i ff-16b-2c-44100hz.flac -af "pan=mono|c0<FL+FR" -ar 44100 -f f32le "pipe:1" > out.bin
```